# How to search JSON array field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, where-clause

I have a column which has json type arrays like

```
row1: ["abc", 10, null, true, false]
row2: ["def", 10, null, true, false]
```

How can i use `where` clause to find `"abc"` contained rows? My json arrays has no key. They only have values.

```
select * from myTable where JSON_SEARCH(myColumn,"all","abc")
```

**returns 0 rows**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MySQL JSON search function `JSON_CONTAINS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```
where json_contains(myColumn, '"abc"')
```

Comment: it returns Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0.

Comment: It requires double quotes like `'"abc"'`. When I try like that, it works

Comment: @hakiko: indeed, thanks for spotting that. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: If you are using the multi-value indexes then you can use functions like MEMBER OF  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html